# if ($(function () { }); is legitimate code, why isn't $(foo())?

Tags: jquery

So, we should all know about the jQuery document-ready handler:

```
$(function () {
  // stuff here
});
```

So basically, if the first parameter for the `$` function is a function, then we run it on document startup, right?

Then why won't this work?

```
$(foo());
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you type `$(foo());` you are actually *calling* `foo` and pass the result to `$`. If you want to use `foo` as a callback, you need to type `$(foo)`.

Answer (score 7):

Because the result from foo() isn't a function.

Use: $(foo);

Answer (score 4):

Here you go.

```
function foo() {
  return function() {
    console.log("Hello World");
  } 
}

$(foo());
```

Now it works. (See what I did there?)

Comment: Clever, but I struggle to conceive of a situation where it would be practical. Have a +1 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**foo is named function** and its not anonymous. So it needs to be used like **$(foo);**

Check this out

[var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant. The problem is that the function needs to be passed instead of the function's result. Whether it's a named function makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need to know that the first parameter of `$` isn't (always) a function. When diving in the jQuery source code, you'll find this function is called:

```
init: function( selector, context, rootjQuery ) {
```

Which handles the following (in order):

```
// Handle $(""), $(null), or $(undefined)
// Handle $(DOMElement)
// The body element only exists once, optimize finding it
// Handle HTML strings (tags, id's etc.)
// HANDLE: $(function)
// Shortcut for document ready
```

Your question is about the last part, which has the following code:

```
// HANDLE: $(function)
// Shortcut for document ready
} else if ( jQuery.isFunction( selector ) ) {
    return rootjQuery.ready( selector );
}
```

Here you'll see that jQuery checks if the selector is a function. In your case, it isn't: Youre **calling** a function, not actually **passing** a function. When the result from foo is a function, it can work.

You can also change it to this:

```
var foo = function() {
   // do your stuff
};

$(foo);
```